# Flutter setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked

Tags: redux, dart, flutter

I am having trouble finding the source to this exception, and the app is quite complex so it is hard to show any relevant part of the code. This is my repository at the point where the error happens:
[Github repo](https://github.com/Schwusch/mah_kronox_flutter/tree/291b0cb5686951b2410dc927757a977a5012fe3e)

I suspect the following code might be the perpetrator:

```
Widget buildResultCard(Map result, BuildContext context) {
    String name = result["value"];
    String description =
        result["label"].replaceAll(new RegExp(r"<(?:.|\n)*?>"), "");
    TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController(text: name);

    Function onPressed = () {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          child: new AlertDialog(
            title: new Text("Name your schedule"),
            content: new TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              controller: controller,
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    String givenName = controller.text;
                    ScheduleMeta schedule = new ScheduleMeta(
                        givenName: givenName,
                        name: name,
                        type: _selectedChoice.value,
                        description: description);

                    scheduleStore
                        .dispatch(new AddScheduleAction(schedule: schedule));

                    scheduleStore.dispatch(
                        new SetCurrentScheduleAction(schedule: schedule));

                    fetchAllSchedules(scheduleStore.state.schedules)
                        .then((weeks) {
                      scheduleStore.dispatch(
                          new SetWeeksForCurrentScheduleAction(weeks: weeks));
                    });

                    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                          content: new Text("Added " + givenName),
                          action: new SnackBarAction(
                              label: "Undo",
                              onPressed: () {
                                scheduleStore.dispatch(
                                    new RemoveScheduleAction(schedule: name));

                                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                                      content: new Text(
                                          "Deleted " + givenName),
                                    ));
                              }),
                        ));

                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: new Text("Add")),
            ],
          ));
    };

    return new Card(
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          new ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.schedule),
            title: new Text(name),
            subtitle: new Text(description),
            isThreeLine: true,
            dense: true,
          ),
          new ButtonTheme.bar(
            child: new ButtonBar(
              children: <Widget>[
                new FlatButton(
                    child: const Text('Add Schedule'),
                    onPressed: scheduleStore.state.schedules
                            .any((schedule) => schedule.name == name)
                        ? null
                        : onPressed)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

The error appears when showing a dialog, and when the user presses a button on the dialog, two Redux store dispatches are sent directly after each other. The UI behind the dialog subscribes to changes in the Redux store.

I thought Dart/Flutter was single-threaded so no collision like this could happen, where it seems like a thread is calling setState() on a widget while another has put a lock on the widget tree.

Is there a way of checking if the widget tree is locked so this can be avoided?

The stack provides this info:

```
I/flutter (13466): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (13466): The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
I/flutter (13466): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked.
I/flutter (13466): This _ModalScope widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is locked.
I/flutter (13466): The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
I/flutter (13466):   _ModalScope([LabeledGlobalKey<_ModalScopeState>#cb4cc]; state: _ModalScopeState#d4c02())
I/flutter (13466): 
I/flutter (13466): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (13466): #0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3250)
I/flutter (13466): #2      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3226)
I/flutter (13466): #3      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1072)
I/flutter (13466): #4      _ModalScopeState._routeSetState (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:473)
I/flutter (13466): #5      ModalRoute.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:552)
I/flutter (13466): #6      ModalRoute.changedInternalState (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:889)
I/flutter (13466): #7      TransitionRoute&&LocalHistoryRoute.removeLocalHistoryEntry (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:317)
I/flutter (13466): #8      LocalHistoryEntry.remove (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:267)
I/flutter (13466): #9      DrawerControllerState.dispose (package:flutter/src/material/drawer.dart:147)
I/flutter (13466): #10     StatefulElement.unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3550)
I/flutter (13466): #11     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1626)
I/flutter (13466): #12     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1624)
I/flutter (13466): #13     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3427)
I/flutter (13466): #14     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1622)
I/flutter (13466): #15     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1624)
I/flutter (13466): #16     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4421)
I/flutter (13466): #17     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1622)
I/flutter (13466): #18     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1624)
I/flutter (13466): #19     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3427)
I/flutter (13466): #20     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1622)
I/flutter (13466): #21     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1624)
I/flutter (13466): #22     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3427)
I/flutter (13466): #23     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1622)
I/flutter (13466): #24     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1624)
I/flutter (13466): #25     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4321)
I/flutter (13466): #26     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1622)
I/flutter (13466): #27     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1624)
I/flutter (13466): #28     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3427)
I/flutter (13466): #29     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1622)
I/flutter (13466): #30     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1624)
I/flutter (13466): #31     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4321)
I/flutter (13466): #32     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1622)
I/flutter (13466): #33     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1624)
I/flutter (13466): #34     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3427)
I/flutter (13466): #35     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1622)
I/flutter (13466): #36     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1624)
I/flutter (13466): #37     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3427)
I/flutter (13466): #38     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1622)
I/flutter (13466): #39     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1624)
I/flutter (13466): #40     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3427)
I/flutter (13466): #41     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1622)
I/flutter (13466): #42     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1624)
I/flutter (13466): #43     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3427)
I/flutter (13466): #44     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1622)
I/flutter (13466): #45     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1624)
I/flutter (13466): #46     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3427)
I/flutter (13466): #47     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1622)
I/flutter (13466): #48     _InactiveElements._unmountAll (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1636)
I/flutter (13466): #49     BuildOwner.finalizeTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2228)
I/flutter (13466): #50     BuildOwner.lockState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2060)
I/flutter (13466): #51     BuildOwner.finalizeTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2227)
I/flutter (13466): #52     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:505)
I/flutter (13466): #53     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:189)
I/flutter (13466): #54     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:688)
I/flutter (13466): #55     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:636)
I/flutter (13466): #56     _drawFrame (file:///b/build/slave/Linux_Engine/build/src/flutter/lib/ui/hooks.dart:70)
I/flutter (13466): (elided one frame from class _AssertionError)
I/flutter (13466): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: Not a full answer but a I got the same error the following way create a Scaffold with a Drawer, put a button in the drawer. bind a callback to the button that causes the app state to change in a way that the whole drawer is not rendered anymore. Then the error is caused by the drawer still being open but not in the widget tree anymore.
The solution for me to call `Navigator.pop(context)` (ie closing the drawer) before calling the `setState()` that causes the drawer to be removed.

Comment: Very good. This happens exactly when you don't close drawer yourself and try to refresh the store. We all know refresh store under the hood calls rebuild and this causes the drawer state to get dirty and it rebuilds as well?

Comment: @LaszloKorte consider to make it as an answer because ur comment is the truest answer in this questions

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is not a thread problem. This error means that you are calling `setState` during the build phase.

A typical example would be the following :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    myParentWidgetState.setState(() { print("foo"); });
    return Container();
}
```

But the setState call may be less obvious. For example a `Navigator.pop(context)` does a `setState` internally. So the following :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    return Container();
}
```

is a no go either.

---

Looking at the stacktrace it seems that simultaneously with the `Navigator.pop(context)`  your modal try to update with new data.

Comment: Rousselet, but **what are the implications of this exception?** My app, for example, seems to work fine. I'm using `notifyListeners()` in the background (I didn't know it would be a problem beforehand) to update a data class while building a widget with `FutureBuilder`, which gives me the same exception.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro it means you're doing something anti-pattern. There's always a way to achieve the same result without being anti-pattern. It's case specific thohg

Comment: kind of sad that I've only found this out right now, I will probably have to modify about 10+ days of work...

Answer (score 47):

As a workaround wrap your code that calling `setState` into `WidgetsBinding.addPostFrameCallback:`

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {}));
```

That way you can be sure it gets executed after the current widget is built.

Comment: This worked perfectly, but I have a question, is this applied only for the widget that this code is put in? or applied for all widget that is shown on screen?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: both the solutions work. you can use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` or `Future.delayed` any of these functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 37):

***Special case*** of using `Scaffold` and `Drawer`:

That fail can also happen if you try to rebuild the tree with opened `Drawer`. For example if you send a message to a `Bloc` that forces rebuilding of the whole page/screen.

Consider to call `Navigator.pop(context)` first in your tap handler.

Answer (score 11):

As the provided answer seems true, I had a work around as, in my case, it was not possible to simply remove it from the build.

I used `Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => setState(() { ... }));` instead of setState and the same for methods that may use  setState as well.

EDIT: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51249946/9714920)

Answer (score 11):

There are couple of options used `setState` inside `build` method and `context` on `initState`

**Wrap your setState inside one of these**

`WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` or `Future.microTask()` or `Timer.run` or `Future.delayed(Duration.zero,`

Example:

```
  WidgetsBinding.instance
              .addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            //valueNotifier.value = _pcm; //provider
            //setState
          });
```

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaanks

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue when making a widget that need to do `Navigator.pop` before returning an Widget in `build`.

Let me call the code from [Rémi Rousselet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51246379/6045409):

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    return Container();
}
```

This code above would cause the error, but you could only pop becasue `context` is in `build`, so how to do?

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(datas != null) // check datas
    {
      SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){ // make pop action to next cycle
        Navigator.of(context).pop(datas); /*...your datas*/
      });
    }
    return Container();
}
```

This method is the combination of the others, but I'm not sure If this is the best practice, If there are any errors, please leave a comment to point me out!

Answer (score 2):

Use `Timer` class,

```
import 'dart:async';

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  Timer.run(() {
    // You can call setState from here
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I control user at LoginScreen on every opening or reload. If user is authenticated i navigate to home. At this point i get same error. It's about navigator's own setState as i understood. addPostFrameCallback or timer fix it.

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (auth.getUser != null) {
      // ERROR
      // Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');

      // SUCCESS
      // WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {
      //       Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
      //     }));

      // SUCCESS
      Timer.run(() {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thaaaaaaaanksss

Answer (score 0):

```
 void initState() {
super.initState();
if (auth.getUser != null) {
  // ERROR
  // Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');

  // SUCCESS
  // WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {
  //       Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
  //     }));

  // SUCCESS
  Timer.run(() {
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
  });
}
```

}

Comment: This is not a thread problem. This error means that you are calling setState during the build phase