# flutter - change child widget with drawer child widget onTap

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am `flutter` beginner.
I have my main page split into 2 custom widgets, `top` widget and `page` widget. And I have a drawer with a few buttons to change the content of the `page` widget.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3VvE6WukeY) and try to swap the widget as per click on the buttons.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var currentpage = 'landing';

    Widget pageWidget;

    switch (currentpage) {
      case 'landing':
        pageWidget = new Landing();
        break;
      case 'visitors':
        pageWidget = new Visitors();
        break;
      default:
    }

return Scaffold(
body:new Container(
child: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Header(), ///<-- widget declared in separated .dart file
        pageWidget
      ],
    )
    )
drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text(
                "UserN3",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black54),
              ),
            ),
            new GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
                print("landing");

                Future.delayed(Duration.zero,(){
                  setState(() {
                    currentpage = 'landing';
                  });
                });
              },
              child: new Text("landing"),
            ),
            new GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
                print("visitors");
                Future.delayed(Duration.zero,(){
                  setState(() {
                    currentpage = 'visitors';
                  });
                });        
              },

              child: new Text("Visitors"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
);
}
```

so the gist is:

I have `switch case` in the build, which will change the `pageWidget` accordingly based on `currentpage`, which will be changed by buttons in the drawer.

But keep getting the same error:

> Another exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked.

As you can see I added `Future.delayed()` based on [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409565/flutter-setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-when-widget-tree-was-locked?rq=1) but the error persist.

After some researching, I got a feeling that it related to how `drawer`  deal with `setState()`, but I am not sure how.

Obviously I still not getting how `flutter` work in terms of `build` and `state`.

What seems to be the problem and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your `currentPage` variable outside your `build` method, because every time you call `setState` the `build` method is called again and the variable doesn't change.

So move this :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var currentpage = 'landing';
```

To this:

```
var currentpage = 'landing';

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```