# Getting EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY & Failed assertion: line 3289 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, tensorflow-lite

From the code below, I would have the the widget _buildResultsWidget with a condition where it would move to a new state and from there when the new page is reached it would stay on for 2 seconds where is would returned me back but there would be an error appearing the moment the condition is activated.

```
import '../main.dart';

class DetectScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  DetectScreen({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _DetectScreenPageState createState() => _DetectScreenPageState();
}


class _DetectScreenPageState extends State<DetectScreen>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _colorAnimController;
  Animation _colorTween;
  bool open = false;
  List<Result> outputs;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //Load TFLite Model
    TFLiteHelper.loadModel().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        TFLiteHelper.modelLoaded = true;
      });
    });

    //Initialize Camera
    CameraHelper.initializeCamera();

    //Setup Animation
    _setupAnimation();

    //Subscribe to TFLite's Classify events
    TFLiteHelper.tfLiteResultsController.stream.listen((value) {
      value.forEach((element) {
        _colorAnimController.animateTo(element.confidence,
            curve: Curves.bounceIn, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
      });

      //Set Results
      outputs = value;

      //Update results on screen
      setState(() {
        //Set bit to false to allow detection again
        CameraHelper.isDetecting = false;
      });

    }, onDone: () {

    }, onError: (error) {
      AppHelper.log("listen", error);
    });
  }

  Widget _buildResultsWidget(double width, List<Result> outputs) {
    open = true;
    return Positioned.fill(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Container(
          height: 200.0,
          width: width,
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: outputs != null && outputs.isNotEmpty
              ? ListView.builder(       // check ? if true or false
              itemCount: outputs.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[

                    Text(
                      outputs[index].label,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: _colorTween.value,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),



                    (outputs[index].label == "General Waste" && outputs[index].confidence > 0.1) == true ?
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => General(),
                      ),
                    ):



                  ],
                );
              })


              : Center(
              child: Text("Wating for model to detect..",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ))),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }



}
void _setupAnimation() {
    _colorAnimController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 5000));
    _colorTween = ColorTween(begin: Colors.green, end: Colors.red)
        .animate(_colorAnimController);
  }

}
```

The condition where the moment it's activated, it would have the error

```
  (outputs[index].label == "General Waste" && outputs[index].confidence > 0.1) == true ?
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => General(),
                      ),
                    ):
```

The code below where it's suppose to bring me to

```
class General extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GeneralState createState() => new _GeneralState();
}

class _GeneralState extends State<General>
{
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    new Timer(const Duration(seconds: 2), onClose); //Timer Here
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
        title: new Text("General Waste"),
      ),
    );
  }

 void onClose() {               
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

And the error would happen the moment the condition is activated

```
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
I/flutter (  803): {loadModel} {Loading model..}
I/flutter (  803): {_initializeCamera} {Initializing camera..}
I/flutter (  803): {_initializeCamera} {Camera initialized, starting camera stream..}
I/flutter (  803): {classifyImage} {Results loaded. 1}
I/flutter (  803): {classifyImage} {0.7169606685638428 , 3, General Waste}
I/flutter (  803): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (  803): The following assertion was thrown building:
I/flutter (  803): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
I/flutter (  803): This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the
I/flutter (  803): process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase
I/flutter (  803): only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework
I/flutter (  803): builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built.
I/flutter (  803): Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
I/flutter (  803): The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
I/flutter (  803):   Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey<OverlayState>#8b7b3]
I/flutter (  803): The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
I/flutter (  803):   SliverList
I/flutter (  803): 
I/flutter (  803): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (  803): #0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4167:11)
I/flutter (  803): #1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4182:6)
I/flutter (  803): #2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1253:14)
I/flutter (  803): #3      OverlayState.rearrange (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:415:5)
I/flutter (  803): #4      NavigatorState._flushHistoryUpdates (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3069:16)
I/flutter (  803): #5      NavigatorState.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3297:5)
I/flutter (  803): #6      _DetectScreenPageState._buildResultsWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:prototypestart/screens/detect_screen.dart:203:43)
I/flutter (  803): #7      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:446:22)
I/flutter (  803): #8      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1134:67)
I/flutter (  803): #9      _HashMap.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/collection_patch.dart:139:29)
I/flutter (  803): #10     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1134:26)
I/flutter (  803): #11     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1147:55)
I/flutter (  803): #12     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2607:19)
I/flutter (  803): #13     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1140:11)
I/flutter (  803): #14     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:354:23)
I/flutter (  803): #15     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1866:58)
I/flutter (  803): #16     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:918:15)
I/flutter (  803): #17     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1866:13)
I/flutter (  803): #18     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:343:5)
I/flutter (  803): #19     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.addInitialChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:427:5)
I/flutter (  803): #20     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:79:12)
I/flutter (  803): #21     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter (  803): #22     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:135:11)
I/flutter (  803): #23     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:375:11)
I/flutter (  803): #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter (  803): #25     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:452:13)
I/flutter (  803): #26     RenderShrinkWrappingViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1783:12)
I/flutter (  803): #27     RenderShrinkWrappingViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1741:20)
I/flutter (  803): #28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter (  803): #29     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter (  803): #30     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter (  803): #31     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter (  803): #32     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter (  803): #33     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter (  803): #34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter (  803): #35     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter (  803): #36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter (  803): #37     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter (  803): #38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter (  803): #39     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter (  803): #40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter (  803): #41     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter (  803): #42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter (  803): #43     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter (  803): #44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter (  803): #45     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter (  803): #46     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
I/flutter (  803): #47     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
I/flutter (  803): #48     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1630:7)
I/flutter (  803): #49     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:887:18)
I/flutter (  803): #50     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:402:19)
I/flutter (  803): #51     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:884:13)
I/flutter (  803): #52     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:284:5)
I/flutter (  803): #53     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1113:15)
I/flutter (  803): #54     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1052:9)
I/flutter (  803): #55     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:968:5)
I/flutter (  803): #59     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:261:10)
I/flutter (  803): #60     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:219:3)
I/flutter (  803): (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
I/flutter (  803): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (  803): {classifyImage} {Results loaded. 1}
I/flutter (  803): {classifyImage} {0.754631757736206 , 3, General Waste}
E/flutter (  803): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2334 pos 18: '!navigator._debugLocked': is not true.
E/flutter (  803): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:42:39)
E/flutter (  803): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:38:5)
E/flutter (  803): #2      _RouteEntry.handlePush.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2334:18)
E/flutter (  803): #3      TickerFuture.whenCompleteOrCancel.thunk (package:flutter/src/scheduler/ticker.dart:398:15)
E/flutter (  803): #4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter (  803): #5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter (  803): #6      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
E/flutter (  803): #7      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
E/flutter (  803): #8      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
E/flutter (  803): #9      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
E/flutter (  803): #10     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:556:7)
E/flutter (  803): #11     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
E/flutter (  803): #12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter (  803): #13     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
E/flutter (  803): #14     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
E/flutter (  803): #15     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
E/flutter (  803): #16     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
E/flutter (  803): 
I/flutter (  803): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 3289 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
I/flutter (  803): {classifyImage} {Results loaded. 1}
I/flutter (  803): {classifyImage} {0.7490702271461487 , 3, General Waste}
I/flutter (  803): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 3289 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
E/flutter (  803): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 3289 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
E/flutter (  803): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:42:39)
E/flutter (  803): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:38:5)
E/flutter (  803): #2      NavigatorState.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3289:12)
E/flutter (  803): #3      Navigator.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1737:34)
E/flutter (  803): #4      _GeneralState.onClose (package:prototypestart/screens/information.dart:31:15)
E/flutter (  803): #5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1180:38)
E/flutter (  803): #6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter (  803): #7      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
E/flutter (  803): #8      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
E/flutter (  803): #9      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
E/flutter (  803): #10     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter (  803): #11     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1003:23)
E/flutter (  803): #12     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:23:15)
E/flutter (  803): #13     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
E/flutter (  803): #14     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
E/flutter (  803): #15     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
E/flutter (  803):
```

But using RaisedButton works just fine

```
      RaisedButton(                      
       child: Text('General Waste'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => General()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409565/flutter-setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-when-widget-tree-was-locked)

Comment: Made a simple sample that can be tested on my current issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61996620/why-cant-i-use-a-condition-to-change-page-but-raised-button-works

Answer (score 0):

1. This becomes quite simple - there's two ways to do this. The simple way is to 
   just use a delayed future with zero delay,
2. which will have dart schedule the call as soon as possible once the current 
   call stack returns to the event loop:

   ```
   Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
   Navigator. ...
   });
   ```