# Confetti Widget not working after await in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, widget

I'm trying to play confetti animation after await call gets completed.

```
TextButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                     //close alert dialog
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();

                    EasyLoading.show(status: "Completeing Task");
                    var res = await dbService.completeTask(
                        comment: comment.text, docId: docId);
                    EasyLoading.dismiss();

                    controller.play();
                    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
                      controller.stop();
                    });
                  },
```

This is my onPressed.

```
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for ConfettiController:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked.
```

I am getting this error.

```
controller.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          isPlaying = controller.state == ConfettiControllerState.playing;
        });
      }
    });
```

This is the controller, when I remove the setstate, the error gone. But, then also confetti is not playing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409565/flutter-setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-when-widget-tree-was-locked does this help?

Comment: @OzanTaskiran I tried that, error gone. But, confetti animation not playing

Comment: Can yo try to remove the await? Doesn't make sense to me to await the 2 seconds